# Does car choice matter in Need for Speed: Hot Pursuit?

Tags: need-for-speed-hot-pursuit-2010

Is there any serious difference between cars in NFS: Hot Pursuit in a given tier? I usually pick at random, but should I be looking at the top speed/HP/etc stats when picking the car to drive for an event?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Definitely; the differences between the cars isn't as obvious as more sim-oriented games like FM3 or NFS:Shift, but they do handle/drift/accelerate noticeably differently; there were a couple challenges I couldn't get past until I unlocked a higher powered vehicle.

Comment: What about damage tolerance?